# Azure DevOps api to get all run details for particular test case

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am looking for an API which has to return multiple run information for a test case with plan id and suite id as a parameter. When I searched getting only the lastTestRunId details in most of the APIs.
Is there a way to get all runs for particular test case Id?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#testrun

searched in above link.

Answer (score 0):

As of this time, however, querying runs by test cases is not supported. If your test cases were run by running the test plans, you can query runs by test plans as an alternative method:

Use [Runs - Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get runs for particular **test plan**.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?planIds={test plan id}&api-version=6.0
```

I have tested the REST API and it works perfectly.

Comment: Getting "The request is invalid." tried changing the version to 5.1 and 6 didn't get response. `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/runs?` if I remove version parameter getting the response. `{
      "id": 22,
      "name": "Test Plan test",
      "url": "",
      "isAutomated": false,
      "state": "Completed",
      "totalTests": 1,
      "incompleteTests": 0,
      "notApplicableTests": 0,
      "passedTests": 1,
      "unanalyzedTests": 0,
      "revision": 0,
      "webAccessUrl": ""
    }`   I cannot find where to apply testCaseFilter?

Comment: @Jay K I'm sorry for my late reply and misunderstanding of your question. I have rewritten my answer and hope can help you.